# Fetch multiple records from multiple database using single query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as follows:-

Users (Table1)

```
id name email     passs
1  u1   uemail1   pass1
2  u2   uemail2   pass2
3  u3   uemail3   pass3
4  u4   uemail4   pass4
```

Messages (Table2)

```
mess_id sender receiver message_text  send_time
1        1     2        text1         2019-03-25 09:39:05
2        1     2        text2         2019-03-30 15:10:54  
3        1     3        text3         2019-03-30 15:11:59
4        1     4        text4         2019-03-30 15:12:48
5        1     4        text5         2019-03-30 15:13:53
6        4     1        text6         2019-04-09 09:26:53
```

The logged in user is u1 and i want to get the latest conversation which is the 6th one okay.

Now what i want is to find the latest conversation of u1 and with whom and then find the details from users table of other user with whom u1 had the latest conversation

I hope you got my question and it's clear to everyone.

How can i do all this is 1 query

The result will be the other user's detail like this in the above case the user will be u4

```
id name email     passs
4  u4   uemail4   pass4
```

So far i have tried this but not getting the result what i wanted

```
select name from users where id=(select receiver_id,sender_id from messages where receiver_id or sender_id=1 order by send_time desc limit 1)
```

Comment: What should be the expected output in tabular format ?

Comment: the output will be the user details like name etc

Comment: Add the expected output in tabular format to question. In the same way, as you have specified the table structure(s).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include what you have tried that is not producing the result you need.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya please check the question again i have added the result which i wanted

Comment: @Dave kindly check the question again i have added what i tried so far

Comment: Any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to determine the other user id in a Derived Table, and then join this to the user table, to get the user details.

```
SELECT 
  u.* 
FROM 
  user AS u 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT
    IF(sender <> 1, sender, receiver) AS other_user  /*Logged-in User Id is mentioned here */
  FROM messages 
  WHERE sender = 1 OR receiver = 1  /*Logged-in User Id is mentioned here */
  ORDER BY send_time DESC LIMIT 1   /*Get the latest message row */
) AS dt ON dt.other_user = u.id
```

`IF(sender <> 1, sender, receiver)` determines the other user id. If `sender` is not **1** (logged-in user), then we consider `sender` as the other user, else `receiver`. This is based on a (mostly valid) assumption that the `sender` and `receiver` will always be different values.

Comment: Thanks a lot madhur i need the if condition on my query and then i get what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat complex but very general way of solving the problem. It finds the maximum send/receive time for each user in a derived table, then `JOIN`s that to the `messages` table to find the other user related to that message, and then `JOIN`s that again to the `users` table to find that user's details. The user of interest is specified in the `WHERE` clause at the end of the query.

```
SELECT u2.*
FROM users u1
JOIN (SELECT user, MAX(send_time) AS send_time
      FROM (SELECT sender AS user, MAX(send_time) AS send_time
            FROM messages
            GROUP BY sender
            UNION
            SELECT receiver, MAX(send_time)
            FROM messages
            GROUP BY receiver) mt
      GROUP BY user) mt ON mt.user = u1.id
LEFT JOIN messages m1 ON m1.sender = mt.user AND m1.send_time = mt.send_time
LEFT JOIN messages m2 ON m2.receiver = mt.user AND m2.send_time = mt.send_time
JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = COALESCE(m1.receiver, m2.sender)
WHERE u1.id = 1
```

Output:

```
id  name    email   passs
4   u4      uemail4 pass4
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aRHXWG5Rqj7CEttwcaVQ5m/0)

Comment: Thanks nick for answering but i got the my solution from madhur's answer